# Is this case gives a contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I come across with this case: The real sequence does not converges and there exist a **subsequence** that converges. Is this gives a contradiction.

Comment: What's the question?  The situation you describe is perfectly possible.  Consider $a_n=n$ if $n$ is even and $a_n=0$ if $n$ is odd.  is that what you were asking?

Comment: No.  There is no contradiction to that and it occurs often.  Consider a sequence where every third third element forms a sequence that converges but the other elements are completely arbitrary.  The whole sequence does not converge but the subsequence of every third element does.  e.g.  $\pi, e, 1, 59, 87, \frac 12, 92, \sqrt {17}, \frac 14, umptyseven, 80 gazillion, \frac 18, eleventynine, \sqrt{icecream}+5^7, \frac 1{16}, googal, ....$ that clearly does not converge but the subsequence $1, \frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 18, \frac 1{16},....$ does.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing weird about that. The sequence is convergent when every subsequent is convergent to the same limit. Consider the following sequence: $a_n=(-1)^n$. Odd elements converge to $-1$, even to $1$, but the sequence does not converge.

Comment: Nitpick.  That's not the "definition" of convergence but equivalent condition.

Comment: @fleablood thanks, edited

Answer (score 2):

Not a contradiction at all and a very common occurance.

If you have a subsequence that converges, the terms that are *not* in the subsequence can... do whatever on earth they'd like.  They have nothing to with the terms in the subsequence and the terms in a subsequence can not "influence" the other terms.

Lets suppose you have $b_k = \frac 1{2^n}$ and $b_k\to 0$.

And you have a sequence $a_{3k} = b_k$ and $a_{3k+1}= 7$ and $a_{3k+2} = k$.

That the sequence $a_k$ is $\frac 12, 7, 1, \frac 14, 7, 2, \frac 18, 7, 3, \frac 1{16}, 7, 4, \frac 1{32},.....$.  This sequence does not converge.  But the subsequence $\frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 18, \frac 1{16}, \frac 1{32},... $ does.  (As does the subsequence $7,7,7,7....$.  But the subsequence $1,2,3,4... $ does not. )

Likewise the sequence $c_n$ where $c_{2k} = b_k$ but $c_{2k+1}$ is utterly arbitrary doesn't converg:

$c_k = \{59, \frac 12, 87, \frac 14, \sqrt \pi, \frac 18, 92.6, \frac 1{16}, 10^{67} - 49, \frac 1{32},e^{\sqrt 2}, \frac 1{64},.....\}$ doesnt converge.

....

I think your confusion is the converse is true.  If you have a sequence that converges, then every subsequence converges as well (and to the same limit).  I'll let you think about that and why it must be obviously true.

But that doesn't go the other way.  A single subsequence converging doesn't mean the whole sequence converges; not even if there are multiple subsequence or infinitely many converging subsequences.  (Only if *every* subsequence converges to the same limit will the that mean the whole sequence converges.)

====

For the nitpickers:

> Yes, what I said is redundant but it isn't false.  If a single subsequence converges that it has every infinite subsequences that converge so if a sequence has one subsequence that converges it has infinitely many.  And if a sequence has two subsequence that converge to different limits then there is a subsequence of infinitely many terms for each that does not converge. And so a seqence converges if and only if *EVERY* subsequence converges.  And if every subsequence converges they all converge to the same limit.